# NameError: name 'useraction' is not defined

Tags: python, global-variables, undefined

I made sure to have global before main(), and I did assign a value to the variable useraction. Why does it still say it's undefined?

```
    import os.path
    from os import path     

    shoppinglist = []   
    global useraction   

    def main():
        Displaylist()     
        RunItemAction()   


    def Displaylist():
        i = 0
        if (len(shoppinglist)>0):
    while (i<=len(shoppinglist)):
        print(shoppinglist[i] +"\n")
        i+=1

        useraction = str(input("Do you want to add, remove, or search for an item? "))
        useraction = useraction.upper()

    def RunItemAction():
        if( useraction == "ADD"):     
            AddItem()
```

Comment: If you use your variable called `useraction` out of any function, it is already global. And if you want to refer it inside any function then use global keyword to refer it inside that function.

Comment: You misunderstand how `global` works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use it like this.

```
    import os.path
    from os import path     

    shoppinglist = []   
    useraction=""  # or any default value you want to give   

    def main():
        Displaylist()     
        RunItemAction()   


    def Displaylist():
        global useraction
        i = 0
        if (len(shoppinglist)>0):
            while (i<=len(shoppinglist)):
                print(shoppinglist[i] +"\n")
                i+=1

        useraction = str(input("Do you want to add, remove, or search for an item? "))
        useraction = useraction.upper()

    def RunItemAction():
        global useraction
        if( useraction == "ADD"):     
            AddItem()
```

Answer (score 0):

Any name defined at the global scope is, by definition, global.

The `global` statement is used in *another* scope to mark a name that would otherwise be local as global.

```
import os.path
from os import path     

shoppinglist = []   

def main():
    Displaylist()     
    RunItemAction()   


def Displaylist():
    global useraction
    i = 0
    if (len(shoppinglist)>0):
        while (i<=len(shoppinglist)):
            print(shoppinglist[i] +"\n")
            i+=1

    useraction = str(input("Do you want to add, remove, or search for an item? "))
    useraction = useraction.upper()

def RunItemAction():
    global useraction
    if( useraction == "ADD"):     
        AddItem()
```

That said, don't use a global variable at all. Pass arguments to functions, and make them return values.